# ros_lib install error--failed to generate libraries for tf package

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-lib, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I create the ros_lib in the sketchbook/libraries, one of the libraries was not installed.And the info of error is as followed.**ps**:Something unnecessary was omited, such as the messages that other libraries was created successfully.

```
    Exporting to .

        [tf]: Unable to find dependency: angles
    ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
    ROS path [1]=/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/install/share
    ROS path [2]=/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/install/stacks
    ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
    ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks. Messages cannot be built.
    ...
    ...
    *** Warning, failed to generate libraries for the following packages: ***
            tf (missing dependency: angles)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/install/share/rosserial_arduino/make_libraries.py", line 91, in <module>
        rosserial_generate(rospack, path+"/ros_lib", ROS_TO_EMBEDDED_TYPES)
    File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosserial_client/make_library.py", line 584, in rosserial_generate
        raise Exception("Failed to generate libraries for: " + str(failed))
    Exception: Failed to generate libraries for: ['tf (missing dependency: angles)']
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229854/ros_lib-install-error--failed-to-generate-libraries-for-tf-package/) by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2016-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved this problem, it lost a package 'tf', which was not installed before successfully. So I used this command to install it.

```
rosdep install tf
```

---

Originally posted by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) with karma: 72 on 2016-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0